# Why is there a discrepancy between $m_n-m_p$ and $m_d-m_u$?

Tags: mass, quarks, neutrons, protons, binding-energy

The difference in mass between a neutron and a proton is $1.3\space  {\rm MeV}/c^2$, but the mass difference between an up quark and a down quark is $2.5\space{\rm MeV}/c^2$. How come the mass differences aren't the same?

Comment: Changing one valence quark's flavour has all sorts of complicated effects on the potential energy binding the nucleon. It literally takes a supercomputer to work out what happens.

Comment: It takes a supercomputer to simulate three quarks?

Comment: Did you by any chance compare the masses of each nucleon with the combined masses of its constituent quarks? If not, then, boy, are you in for a surprise.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I was wondering if the fact that quarks make up only 1% of their mass had anything to do with it.

Comment: Three valence quarks that engage in all four fundamental interactions, the most significant of which is self-interacting, resulting in a complex sea of other quarks & gluons. Also, the strong force had such a large equivalent of the fine structure constant you have to add a _lot_ of terms for precision. So, yes, very involved.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments mention that calculating the mass of a nucleon is extremely complicated, which is true: see [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD). It does require a supercomputer. But the strong force is insensitive to quark flavor, so I'm not sure that any of that complexity is related to this question.

The quark flavors differ not only in mass but also in electric charge, and a naive back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests that the rest of the mass difference could be electromagnetic. The energy needed to bring three charges $q_1,q_2,q_3$ from infinity to a triangle of side $r$ is $k(q_1q_2{+}q_2q_3{+}q_3q_1)/r$. For two down quarks and one up quark, that's $-\frac13 ke^2/r$, and for two up quarks and one down quark, it's zero. That would account for the discrepancy if $\frac13 k e^2/r \approx 1.2\text{ MeV}$, or $r\approx 0.4\text{ fm}$, which is close to the size of a nucleon.

The paper "Electromagnetic proton-neutron mass difference" by Oleksandr Tomalak ([DOI](https://dx.doi.org/10.1140/epjp/s13360-020-00413-9), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02502)) quotes the results of much more sophisticated calculations of the electromagnetic contribution, which hover around 1 MeV with large error margins.